Show me some methods to extract text from interface of an app
I need a method to extract text from the interface of an Android app. I have tried using adb shell screencap, UI Automator dump, and Tesseract OCR, but none of them worked. It seems that the app does not allow these methods (when I open the app on Vysor or scrcpy, the screen is completely black). Someone can help me to solve it please.
